# Rebuild exterior elements of form on submit

Tags: forms, 7

On the user page I display two types of groups a user can be subscribed to: a pending membership or an approved membership. To illustrate this:

[image: Pending and approved group memberships]

The 'cancel membership request' button is the submit button of a form of which only this button is a part. When this button is clicked, a submit callback is called. This does some processing such that the membership request should be no longer in the list. Preferably even, the whole fieldgroup should disappear.

But since the form consists only of the button, `$form_state['rebuild']` can do only something with regard to the button itself, which is not sufficient in this case. Setting `$form_state['redirect']` to the the same page seems not to work either (the page is not rebuilt then).

How can I make the page rebuild so it reflects the changes invoked by the submit button?

Comment: If the form really only consists of the button then you can't accomplish this in the form (by definition when you're within form processing functions you can only effect the form, not arbitrary markup that surrounds it). You'd need to do it wherever the fieldset is generated and the form injected inside it. Far easier would be to move the fieldset inside the form

Comment: But the problem is then that the fieldset can contain multiple groups and thus, multiple submit buttons.